# Timelapse graph representation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to convert next data structure into a list of active processes for Highcharts plotting?

Original result

```
Started At; Taken Time; Number of started processes
1; 12; 1
8; 3; 2
```

to be converted into

```
Time; Active processes
1; 1
2; 1
...
7; 1
8; 3
9; 3
10; 3
11; 1
12; 1
13; 0
```

Comment: Hi @FieryCat, Could you explain your problem more precisely? Also, do you use data from CSV?

Comment: @ppotaczek, mostly in its representation by using Highcharts without a shown above conversion.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/enz4mudL/ is an example with the required data structure. I have used the `seriesMapping` property. Please let me know if this is something that you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Super, thanks @ppotaczek. May you post it as a comment to close the question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `seriesMapping` property to create the required format of data.

```
seriesMapping: [{
  x: 0,
  takenTime: 1,
  y: 2
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/enz4mudL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping